# How to accept mulitple REST query parameters with same id in spring-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

How can I create a rest controller with `spring-mvc` that takes multiple parameters with the same name? `localhost:8080/api?id=12&id=15&id=88`

```
//pseudocode
@RestController
public class MyRest {
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public Object test(@RequestParam value="ids" required=false) List<Integer> ids) {
    Sysout(ids);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?id=12&id=15&id=88` should work automatically with `@RequestParam(value="id") List<Integer> ids`